Autocomplete with Gopls only completing modules
I'm having trouble setting up Go autocomplete with Emacs.
It only autocompletes (some) modules  and nothing else, for example:

Here I would expect to autocomplete the name of the variable above (at the very least)
Completion of modules seems to be hit and miss:

This module is imported with a "github.com/" path and autocomplete works

This one is imported with an alias, and it is not recognized.

In this case the module path does not start with "github.com" and autocomplete does not work.
I have gopls installed:
$ gopls version
golang.org/x/tools/gopls master
    @

and
emacs --version
GNU Emacs 29.3
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.

and this is my goenv:
$ go env
GO111MODULE=''
GOARCH='amd64'
GOBIN=''
GOCACHE='/home/bznein/.cache/go-build'
GOENV='/home/bznein/.config/go/env'
GOEXE=''
GOEXPERIMENT=''
GOFLAGS=''
GOHOSTARCH='amd64'
GOHOSTOS='linux'
GOINSECURE=''
GOMODCACHE='/home/bznein/go/pkg/mod'
GONOPROXY=''
GONOSUMDB=''
GOOS='linux'
GOPATH='/home/bznein/go'
GOPRIVATE=''
GOPROXY='https://proxy.golang.org'
GOROOT='/usr/lib/golang'
GOSUMDB='off'
GOTMPDIR=''
GOTOOLCHAIN='local'
GOTOOLDIR='/usr/lib/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64'
GOVCS=''
GOVERSION='go1.22.3'
GCCGO='gccgo'
GOAMD64='v1'
AR='ar'
CC='gcc'
CXX='g++'
CGO_ENABLED='1'
GOMOD='/dev/null'
GOWORK=''
CGO_CFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_CPPFLAGS=''
CGO_CXXFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_FFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_LDFLAGS='-O2 -g'
PKG_CONFIG='pkg-config'
GOGCCFLAGS='-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build2732918156=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches'


*lsp-log* doesn't show any interesting result for me.
For reference, this is the repo I'm working on: https://github.com/cosmos/ibc-go
I've tried to open the same repo with VSCode which, to my understanding, uses gopls in the same way, and all this cases work fine.
I've tried with Spacemacs and Doom Emacs and both behave (as expected) in the same way.
